# product of an arbitrary topological space with a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

What can we say about the product space (with product topology) $X\times Y$ if $X$ is an arbitrary topological space and $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space?

Do we know from the given information if the projection $\pi:X\times Y\to X$ is open/closed?

Regards

Comment: The projections for a product space are always open.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/projection-map-being-a-closed-map

Answer (score 1):

The product topology is defined in such a way that the projection maps are open. A projection map parallel to a compact factor is always closed; the factor need not be Hausdorff. This is a standard basic result in topology; you can find a proof in the first paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22764/12042).

Beyond that very little can be said about $X\times Y$.