# If Y is compact, then the projection map of $X \times Y$ is a closed map.

Tags: general-topology

This is a question from munkres section 26 problem 7.  Show if Y is compact, then the projection $\pi_1:X \times Y \rightarrow X$ is a closed map.  My question is why this is not trivial. Essentially we want that if $C_X \times  C_Y$ is a closed subset of $X \times Y$ then, $\pi_1(C_X \times  C_Y)=C_X$ is closed.  But if $C_X \times  C_Y$ is closed, then is it not the case that both $C_X $ and $ C_Y$ must be closed? Therefore $C_X$ must be closed.  Thus $\pi_1$ is a closed map.  Why do we even need $Y$ compact?

Comment: Why do you think it's enough to consider closed sets of the form $C_X \times C_Y$?

Comment: The set $\{\langle x,y\rangle:x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ that is not of the form $A\times B$ for any sets $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R$.

Comment: The projection of $\{(x,y)\mid xy=1\}$ from ${\Bbb R}^2$ into $\Bbb R$ is not closed.  So, you definitely need $Y$ compact.

Comment: I refer you to the answers on this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/projection-map-being-a-closed-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closed sets of $X \times Y$ in the product topology are complements of open sets. We know that the open sets are given by unions of sets of the form $A \times B$ where $A$, and $B$ are open sets in respectively $X$ and $Y$. Hence the closed sets are given by intersections of complements of sets of this form. However $(X \times Y) - A \times B $ is not $(X - A) \times (Y - B)$, since the complement is defined to be all elements in $X \times Y$ that are not in $A \times B$, we must have $$X \times Y - (A \times B) = (X - A) \times Y \cup X \times (Y - B) $$Hence the closed sets are intersections of sets of this form, however intersections aren't necessarily preserved under images. Hence you can't just consider sets of the form $C_X \times C_Y$. I think I have done this exercise in Munkres book some time ago, and if I am not mistaken, you can use the tube lemma to prove this.