# Is projection of a closed set $F\subseteq X\times Y$ always closed?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, product-space, closed-map

If we have closed subset $F$ of product $X \times Y$ (product topology) does it mean that $p_1(F)$ (projection on first coordinate) is closed in $X$ and $p_2(F)$ in $Y$ are closed? If not, why not (some counterexample or explanation please =)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not always true. A counterexample is $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, $F=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:xy=1\}$.

Comment: Thank you =D so simple and yet I couldn't think of counterexample for days...

Answer (score 13):

As you have known, it is not always true. However, putting some conditions on the spaces, we have the following lemma:

> If $Y$ is [compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), then the projection $\pi_1: X \times Y \to X$ is a closed map.

It means that if $C$ is closed in $X \times Y$, then $\pi_1(C)$ is closed in $X$.

You can find the proof of the lemma [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/projection-map-being-a-closed-map/673505#673505).