# $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid 0\le x \lt 1, 0\le y \le 1\}$ is not compact

Tags: compactness

**Claim**

$A = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid 0\le x \lt 1, 0\le y \le 1\}$ is not compact.

I want to prove above claim. I might need to find out finite sub-cover of open cover of given set A. It requires me two step simultaneously, first think about open cover (which is a union of infinite open balls) second, then reduce the open cover but to be still infinite.

How could I construct like that example? Is there any easier or alternative way to show the claim not actually construct some specific examples?

Comment: the set is not closed

Comment: Hint.  The set is not closed. How can you tell it is not closed? Base your open cover on thet.  Eg. Let you open cove be all the with some distance of (1,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $c\in [0,1)$, let $U_c=\{\,(x,y)\in X\mid x<c\,\}$. Then $U_c$ is open, $\bigcup_{c\in[0,1)} U_c=A$, but no finite subcover $U_{c_1}\cup\ldots\cup U_{c_n}$ suffices as it does not contain the point $(\frac{1+\max_i c_i}{2},0)\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Heine-Borel theorem: the compact sets are precisely the closed and bounded sets. Your set is bounded; is it closed? (Hint: if it were closed, then you could use [this lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422247/is-projection-of-a-closed-set-f-subseteq-x-times-y-always-closed). Or "just do it".)

Comment: but compact sets are not always closed and bounded but it depends on the metric space. isn't it?

Comment: @jackerysmith The question as stated is using the Euclidean metric, where Heine-Borel is true. (In general, the Euclidean topology is assumed when no other topology is given.)

Comment: @PatricStevens. Got it

Answer (score 0):

For $A=\{(x,y)|0<x\leq1,0\leq y\leq1\}$

Let $a_n=\left(\frac{1}{n},0\right)$.

Hence, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n\notin A$, but $a_n\in A$.

For $A=\{(x,y)|0\leq x<1,0\leq y\leq1\}$

Let $a_n=\left(\frac{n}{n+1},0\right)$.

Hence, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n\notin A$, but $a_n\in A$.

The given was changed some times.

Comment: $(0,0) \in A$. You want $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens The given was changed. Now $(0,0)\notin A$.