# Graph of f is closed

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

I am working on this problem today:

Let $G=\{(x,f(x))|x\in X\}$ be the graph of the function $f:X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $Y$ is compact. If $G$ is closed in $X\times Y$, show that $f$ is continuous.

The hint of the problem is to use the Tube lemma somewhere. If I let $U$ be an open set in $Y$, $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, and $V$ be an open subset in $X\times Y$ that contains $\{x\}\times Y$, then I cannot guarantee that the neighborhood $V_x$ such that $V_x\times Y\subset W$ is entirely inside $f^{-1}(U)$. Can someone tell me how I could use the tube lemma?

I feel like the solution in another post to the same problem does not really use the tube lemma.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compact topological space with closed graph implies continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769333/compact-topological-space-with-closed-graph-implies-continuity)

Comment: No, but it does. We prove projections are closed maps using the Tube Lemma. You can rejig the proof to only say "tube lemma" quite straightforwardly if you wish, since "Tube Lemma --> projections are closed" is a simple proof