# If C is a closed subset of the set $X \times Y$ then is $\pi_{1}(C)$ closed also?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $X \times Y$ be given the product topology, let $\pi_{1}:X\times Y \to X$ be the canonical projection.

Now suppose $C$ is a closed subset of $X \times Y$, does $\pi_{1}(C)$ necessarily have to be closed?

I have been told you have to use the fact that the projection of open rectangles is open in $X$. As well as the fact that the projection of open subsets of $X \times Y$ are also open in $X$, but I can't figure it out still.

Answer (score 4):

No, a standard example is $X=Y=\Bbb R$ and $C$ the graph of $xy=1$.

Comment: How can we set $C$ as $xy = 1$? Can we treat this function as a closed set in the product topology?

Comment: @user501050 Recall I said "the graph of ..."

Answer (score 0):

This will hold for all $C$ (i.e. $\pi$ is a closed map) iff $Y$ is compact. I show this in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22764/4280), e.g.