# "Kuratowski-Mrówka theorem" Need reference

Tags: general-topology, analysis, reference-request, compactness

I need a reference "book or paper" for this theorem:

> A Hausdorff space $X$ is compact if and only if the projection
>   $P_{Y}:X\times Y\to Y$ is a closed map.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compacit%C3%A9_(math%C3%A9matiques)#cite_note-9

Thank you

Comment: The Hausdorff is not needed, actually. Your article also mentions that (you can just use "quasi-compact" and drop the Hausdorff).

Comment: The Wikipedia article you quoted, I now see, has many of the same quotations I gave below.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a reasonably recent and trusted reference, I'd quote

Engelking "General Topology", revised and completed edition (1989) 
Thm. 3.1.16 (the Kuratowski theorem).

In the historical notes Engelking mentions that the 1931 paper

*Evaluation de la classe borélienne d'un ensemble de points à l'aide des symboles logiques*, Fund. Math 17 (1931), 249-272 by K.Kuratowski

proved the left to right direction for compact metric spaces, after which

Bourbaki *Topologie générale* ch I et II, Paris (1940)

generalised this to general topological spaces. Finally,

S. Mrówka in *Compactness and product spaces*, Coll. Math. 7 (1959-1960), 23-25

showed that the closed projection property characterised compact spaces.

If you just want to  see a proof, look at [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22764/4280) e.g.