# For a closed subset $F ⊂ X × Y$ , the image $π(F )$ need not be closed in Y

Tags: general-topology, analysis, projection, product-space, closed-map

I have the following question from an exam

> If $(X, d_X)$ is compact, show that every sequence in $X$ has a
> subsequence converging to a point of $X$. Deduce that the projection
> map $\pi$ then has the property that, for any closed subset $F \subset
> X \times Y$, the image $\pi(F)$ is closed in $Y$. Give an example to
> show that this fails if $(X, d_X)$ is not assumed compact.

I was able to do the first two parts just fine, however, I am struggling to find a counter example to the last part. I think that it is due to an unease with dealing with the open and closed sets in the product topology. That is, whenever I make up some product topology I find it hard to immidietly tell if a set is open or closed, even if it the product topology as simple components.

Regardless, I tried to construct a counter example. First I thought of some the graph of some curve, however, if the curve is continuous then I will never be able to find an example as desired.

I am getting the sense that this problem will be hard with $\mathbf{R}$, however, I am not sure what other space to try.

**Question:** How does one think of the last part of the problem and what is such an example?

Comment: See the accepted answer in [Projection map being a closed map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22697/projection-map-being-a-closed-map)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. It does seem give an example but with no explanation. How does one even know that the set the author has given is closed? This is more to the essence here - I am struggling to think about open and closed sets in the product topology and want to use this, the above, question as a tool of understanding it better.

Comment: I'm guessing you can see that the image of $\{xy = 1\}$ is not closed. Do you see why $(x, y) \mapsto xy$ is a continuous map $\mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}$? Or more directly, given an $(x_0, y_0)$ such that $x_0 y_0 \ne 1$, do you see why there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \times (y_0 - \epsilon, y_0 + \epsilon)$ is disjoint from $\{xy = 1\}$? This shows that the complement $\{xy \ne 1\}$ is open.

Comment: In a sense all the answers are the same answer: if $f  :X \to Y$ is continuous (and $Y$ is Hausdorff) then the graph of $f$ is closed as a subset of $X \times Y$, and its image under the projection to $Y$ is the same as the image of $f$, which may not be closed. @CopyPasteIt's answer further restricts to a specific sequence exhibiting the non-closedness.

Answer (score 1):

Let me also add one example that I like. Consider $X=\mathbb{R}=Y$ and

$$ F=\{ (x,e^x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ x\in \mathbb{R} \}. $$

This is closed. Indeed, pick a sequence $(x_n,y_n)_{n\geq 1} \subseteq F$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (x_n,y_n)=(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. By definition this means $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n =u, \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n =v$. However, as $(x_n,y_n)\in F$ we know that $y_n = e^{x_n}$ and hence
$$ v=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{x_n} = e^u $$
as the exponential is continuous. Hence, we get that $(u,v)=(u,e^u)\in F$ and therefore $F$ is closed.

Now let's project $F$ on the second coordinate. We get

$$ \pi(F) = \{ e^x \ : \ x\in \mathbb{R}\} = (0,\infty) $$

which is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\omega$ be the nonnegative integers with the discrete topology and $Y=\omega\cup\{\infty\}$ be its one point compactification. Then $H=\{(n,n):n\in\omega\}$ is closed in $X\times Y$ but $\pi_Y[H]=\omega$ is not closed in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the subsset $F = \{(n,\frac{1}{n}) \mid n \text{ is an integer greater than 1}\}$ of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$.

For integer $k \ge 1$ define

$\quad U_k = \{((x,y) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \mid k \lt x \lt k+1\}$

$\quad V_k = \{((x,y) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \mid (k+1)^{-1} \lt y \lt  k^{-1}\}$

and  define

$\quad U_0 = \{((x,y) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \mid -\infty \lt x \lt 1\}$

$\quad V_0 = \{((x,y) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \mid 1 \lt y \lt  +\infty\}$

Clearly for $k \ge 0$ each of the sets $U_k$ and $V_k$ is open. Moreover, it can be shown that these sets along with the set $F$ partitions $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$. It follows that $F$ is closed in $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, but the projection $\pi_y$ onto the $2^{nd}$ coordinate sends $F$ to

$$ \{k^{-1} \mid k \ge 1\}$$

which is not a closed set in $\Bbb R$.